# Attach to Remote C++ Process with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a c++ program running on a remote machine.
I'd like to debug it from my machine.
I've installed remote debugging services (msvsmon.exe ) on the server.
Firewalls are not active not in the client nor in the server.
The program is running on the server (.pdb file is also there). 
In the client I open the project in VS2010 , I go to debug->attach to process.
In the qualifier field I copy the value of the server name in msvsmon.exe.
When I hit enter, I get an error prompt saying :

"Unable to connect to Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named Administrator@TESTER1, the requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found"

In the server, the Authentication mode in msvsmon.exe is set to Windows Authentication.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards,
Omer.

Comment: I think this is a DNS error.  Double-check that you can connect to a share on that server.  Other than fixing the name server, a possible workaround is to use the IP address instead (Administrator@192.168.1.42)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:

[How to: Set Up Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) from Microsoft

[Remote debugging with Visual Studio 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146838/Remote-debugging-with-Visual-Studio-2010) from CodeProject

In your case, take note of the suggestions regarding native debugging and windows authentication.

In my experiences with remote debugging a machine that is on my local network, I bypass windows authentication and setup the remote msvsmon.exe to allow anyone to connect to port 4015. So, then in the 'Attach to Process' dialog I select Transport > Remote (Native only with no authentication) and for the Qualifier I enter TESTER1:4015 or TheIPAddress:4015 if the name of the PC cannot be resolved.

Comment: I can now currently attach to process but can not set breakpoints.

Comment: each time I'm trying to add a breakpoint it has an exclamation mark near its tool tip sais:

Comment: " the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document" .
Any ideas how can I resolve it?

Comment: Make sure you are compiling the application as Debug and copy it to the test machine.  My guess is you may be copying the release build of the app to the test machine.

Comment: Thanks Roger. I'm compiling in debug and copying the pdb and exe to the remote server. Any idea what else can cause this?

Comment: Things to try: Don't copy the pdb file to the test machine. Make the exe project (the one you want to debug) the startup project for the solution. Make sure your project's Debug Working Directory is set to the folder where the build output resides (exe and pdb files).